# Proving an Integral inequality from a given integral inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

**Problem:** Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous, non-negative function on $[0, 1]$, with

$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{-f(x)}dx \geq \int_{0}^{1}e^{-g(x)}dx. $$

Prove that,

$$\int_{0}^{1}g(x)e^{-f(x)}dx \geq \int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{-g(x)}dx. $$

This problem is an equivalent form of a problem from the book "More Calculus of a variable" by Peter Mercer. In the original problem there was $xf(x)$ and $xg(x)$ in place of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.
I couldn't make much progress. I tried contradiction and method which led to conlclude that its enough to show,

$$e^{g(x)}-e^{f(x)}+f(x)e^{f(x)}-g(x)e^{g(x)} < 0.$$ But sadly this is not true in general.

I also tried integration by parts to seperate $\displaystyle\int^{1}_{0}e^{-g(x)}\,dx$ from $\displaystyle\int^{1}_{0}f(x)e^{-g(x)}\,dx$ to use the given inequality. But I didn't happen.

Please help me. I am in  high school so please don't use any very advanced inequality.

Comment: Periods and commas go inside of double $'s.

Comment: I am not sure your question is equivalent to the one from the book... doing it for $xg(x)$ instead of $g(x)$ forces the integrand, $xg(x)e^{-f(x)}$, to be small near 0. This property is not imposed if the integrand were only $g(x)e^{-f(x)}$

Comment: @enthdegree, but $f(x)$ is also replaced by $xf(x)$

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that this is true. By symmetry it would follow that if $\int_{0}^{1}e^{-f(x)}dx  = \int_{0}^{1}e^{-g(x)}dx$ then  also $\int_{0}^{1}g(x)e^{-f(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{-g(x)}dx$. – Are there any additional conditions on $f$, $g$ ?

Comment: @Cupid my complaint still holds even with my error

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion does *not* hold. As an example, take
$$
  f(x) = x \, , \quad g(x) = 1 - \log(e-1) \, .
$$
Then
$$
 \int_0^1 e^{-f(x)} \, dx = \int_0^1 e^{-g(x)} \, dx = 1 - \frac 1e \, ,
$$
but
$$
\int_0^1 g(x) e^{-f(x)} \, dx = (1 - \log(e-1) ) (1 - \frac 1e) \approx 0.29 \\
 < \int_0^1 f(x)e^{-g(x)} \, dx = \frac 12 (1 - \frac 1e) \approx 0.31 \, .
$$

Answer (score -1):

From the original inequality:
$$\int_0^1 e^{-f(x)}dx\ge\int_0^1e^{-g(x)}dx \rightarrow f(x)\le g(x)$$
Normally you would want to prove this specifically but if you are in highschool we will just take it as intuitive. Also, we have the statement:
$$e^{-f(x)} \ge e^{-g(x)}$$
Using this:
$$g(x)e^{-f(x)}  \ge f(x)e^{-f(x)}$$
But also:
$$f(x)e^{-f(x)}  \ge f(x)e^{-g(x)}$$
Therefore:
$$g(x)e^{-f(x)}  \ge f(x)e^{-f(x)}\ge f(x)e^{-g(x)}$$
Drop the middle term then integrate:
$$g(x)e^{-f(x)}  \ge f(x)e^{-g(x)} \rightarrow \int_0^1 g(x)e^{-f(x)} dx  \ge \int_0^1f(x)e^{-g(x)}dx$$

Comment: Why is the first statement obvious? Does the fact that $1/2 = \int_0^1 x \, dx > \int_0^1 (1/4) \,dx = 1/4$ imply that $x > 1/4$ on $[0,1]?$

Comment: I disagree with your "intuitive" assertion that $\int_0^1 e^{-f(x)} dx \geq \int_0^1 e^{-g(x)}dx\Rightarrow f(x)\leq g(x)$... Take $f(x)$ to be a bump near x=0.1, and $g(x)$ to be the same bump near x=0.9... then the integral inequality holds, but the functional inequality obviously does not.